# Completable.fromAction not executing the code in rjava2

Tags: android, rx-java2

```
 Completable.fromAction(() -> startRecording())
 .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
 .subscribe(() -> {
        boolean startSuccess = mMediaRecorder.getState() == MediaRecorder.RECORDING_STATE;
        if (startSuccess) {
            updateView();
            startRepeatingTask();
        }
    },throwable -> {
        Logger.info("Record failed with exception" + throwable);
    }).dispose();
```

I am trying to execute code in background using Completable.fromAction but it is not executing the code if I use subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).

if I remove subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()), it is executing the code in main thread.  I want to executing the code in background thread.

Comment: You're calling `dispose` right after you subscribe. Doesn't this cancel the whole thing? If you remove the call to `dispose` does it work? If so I can explain better with an answer what's happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People have already highlighted the problem with your code in the comments - you call `dispose()` on the `Disposable` that your `Completable` returns immediately. This means you cancel your `Completable` before it has even started. Alter your code to store your `Disposable` in an instance variable, and call `dispose()` only when you are no longer interested in receiving it completing. This usually happens in a lifecycle callback like `onPause` or `onStop`. For example:

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity {

    private final CompositeDisposable disposables = new CompositeDisposable(); 

    //...

    disposables.add(Completable.fromAction(() -> startRecording())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) //Note: `updateView` implies UI work. Should you also have `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread)?
        .subscribe(() -> {
            boolean startSuccess = mMediaRecorder.getState() == MediaRecorder.RECORDING_STATE;
            if (startSuccess) {
                updateView();
                startRepeatingTask();
            }
        }, throwable -> {
        Logger.info("Record failed with exception" + throwable);
        }));

     //Later, in some other lifeycle callback when you no longer care about updates...
     disposables.clear();
```

Comment: why it is working when subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) is not added?

Comment: Probably because it's running synchronously. The work to be done blocks on the calling thread, and then dispose is called. When you involve another thread, the work is scheduled on that separate thread but not executed - before it can be executed, you dispose it.

Answer (score 0):

change the `.fromAction` to `.fromCallable`

Callables are designed to perform a single emitter, and then complete. Actual doc explanation [here](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Completable.html#fromCallable-java.util.concurrent.Callable-).

The `.fromAction` is a bit different. Docs [here](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Completable.html#fromAction-io.reactivex.functions.Action-).

Comment: The `fromAction` isn't the problem with the OP's setup. The OP disposes the flow immediately after subscription, which when the `fromAction` runs in the background thread, will race with the execution and dispose it prematurely.